# Joomla poll not working with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, joomla

On my Joomla website the Joomla poll extension (down, right) or any other Joomla poll only works in Firefox, Safari and all the other browser but not in IE8 or lower versions.
I need a poll on my site and 95% of my site visitors use IE8, its frustrating.

How can I get any joomla poll to work in IE8 ?

It's strange but IE8 displays the poll good, like Firefox, but you can't vote with it?

Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Can you provide us a link of the extensions you're using, or maybe a screenshot of the exactly behavior of the poll?

Answer (score 1):

If you could provide a URL so we could take a look, that would be helpful.

My guess is there is a DIV which is being rendered over the area (with a higher z-index) where the button is.  You could use Firefox and Firebug to see if that is the case.

But it would make sense as the IE family has a peculiar way of rendering.

To test, you could also try changing the template, or moving the poll module to a different position - away from anything else.